# Difference between these two joining table approaches?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Consider we have two tables, `Users` and `Posts`. `user_id` is the foreign key in `Posts` table and is primary key in `Users` table.

Whats the difference between these two sql queries?

```
select user.name, post.title 
  from users as user, posts as post 
 where post.user_id = user.user_id;
```

vs.

```
select user.name, post.title 
  from users as user join posts as post
 using user_id;
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Other than syntax, for the small snippet, they work exactly the same.  But if at all possible, always write new queries using ANSI-JOINs.

As for semantically, the comma notation is used to produce a CARTESIAN product between two tables, which means produce a matrix of all records from table A with all records from table B, so two tables with 4 and 6 records respectively produces 24 records.  Using the WHERE clause, you can then pick the rows you actually want from this cartesian product.  However, MySQL doesn't actually follow through and make this huge matrix, but semantically this is what it means.

A JOIN syntax is the ANSI standard that more clearly defines how tables interact. By putting the `ON` clause next to the `JOIN`, it makes it clear what links the two tables together.

Functionally, they will perform the same for your two queries. The difference comes in when you start using other `[OUTER]` JOIN types.

For MySQL specifically, comma-notation [does have one difference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

> STRAIGHT_JOIN is similar to JOIN, except that the left table is always read before the right table. This can be used for those (few) cases for which the join optimizer puts the tables in the wrong order.

However, it would [not be wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512294/when-to-use-straight-join-with-mysql) to bank on this difference.

Comment: In MySQL, there is a subtle difference between `,` (== `STRAIGHT_JOIN`) and `JOIN`.

Comment: so comma-notation is same as inner join ? and will Cartesian product take more resources then join on ??

Comment: @jason [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) is a mathematical operation between two sets, used to describe the SET-based operation in SQL. Your two queries are for all intensive purposes the same, so neither will take more resources

Comment: MySQL will notice the WHERE clause and not do any more work than it has to. It's _equivalent_ to a full Cartesian product followed by a WHERE filter, but that's not what it actually does. This is all detailed in the [JOIN Syntax section](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) of the MySQL manual. [What @Richard said while I was writing this. :)]

Comment: I will like to learn how sql query gets interpreted , which part of query has higher preference and get executed first any links to such resources would be helpful thanks .

Comment: As long as the result is equivalent, theoretically the arrangements of the parts is inconsequential. Any difference exposes a failure of the query optimizer (that will hopefully be detected and corrected in the next version.) That's one of the consequences of SQL being a declarative language rather than a procedural language.

Comment: `,` is not `straight_join`.

Answer (score 4):

```
where post.user_id = user.user_id
```

Here you are making a conditional statement

```
from users as user join posts as post using user_id
```

Here you are joining two tables using the foreign key

At the end is just the same but JOIN is better used for more advanced queries...

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL [JOIN syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html), `CROSS JOIN`, `INNER JOIN`, and `JOIN` are all the same. A comma-separated table list is a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL manual on page https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html makes this point about the difference between the two approaches:

> However, the precedence of the comma operator is less than that of
>   INNER JOIN, CROSS JOIN, LEFT JOIN, and so on. If you mix comma joins
>   with the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of
>   the form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur.