# How to retrieve all data from two table in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables: "tbl_file" and "tbl_product"

I need to retrieve all data from both tables where "tbl_file" has a name, city, country and license number. Table "tbl_product" only stores the brand and type of product(1 - 5).

My problem is that when i try to retrieve data and it only display the    "tbl_file" data only and empty for "tbl_product".

Below is the code :

```
$sql = "SELECT tbl_file.* ,tbl_product.* 
        FROM tbl_file ,tbl_product 
        WHERE CompName LIKE '%$company_name%' 
           OR License_No LIKE '%$License_no%'";
```

Comment: Read up on [table joins](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Comment: `WHERE tbl_file.linkColumn = tbl_product.link_column` You needto tell MYSQL how these 2 tables are linked

Comment: related/duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294311/difference-between-these-two-joining-table-approaches http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause

Comment: Thanks @Xorifelse