# How to stop echo data multiple times

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, fetch

I am trying to get data from multiple tables and I got them while fetching data I am getting same data multiple time

How to stop echo data multiple times

```
<?php
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT t1.id,t2.id from t1,t2ORDER BY t1.id DESC ');
$stmt->execute();   
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        extract($row);
}
?>
```

This I am getting data but multiple times like t1 have 10 ids t2 have 20 ids so I got 30 IDs on the display

Comment: show your schema, show your expected out put. May be you need to use `JOIN`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/6zbYn

Comment: but i am getting data like this https://imgur.com/a/SDCmo

Comment: Always add all question details to your question as an Edit.  Please delete your comments that contain question details.  I think you will want a different JOIN.

Comment: Time to research the different JOINs.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294311/difference-between-these-two-joining-table-approaches

Comment: update  your question add  a real data sample and the expcted .. result  ..

Answer (score 0):

for avoid duplicated  rows  you could use  distinct

```
  $DB_con->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT  t1.id,t2.id from t1,t2 ORDER BY t1.id DESC ');
```

but in your FROM clause you are using a cross join  (a cartesian product between each row of a table multiplied by  each row for other table)

could be you need  a join   alia a condition between tables column thate relate the tow table ed.

```
  $DB_con->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT  t1.id,t2.id 
  from t1
  INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id ORDER BY t1.id DESC ');
```

*the join based on  t1.id = t2.id  is just a sample you should check for the evnetual real joining condition*