# Mysql optimize slow query with explain

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, explain

I'm working on MySQL 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.1.

I have the need to create a query that can sort results by date and by a score.

I read the documentation and the posts here on stackoverflow (specifically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633406/using-index-using-temporary-using-filesort-how-to-fix-this)) about how to optimize a query but I'm still struggling to do it well.
The key findings is that to avoid the use of a temporary table the ORDER BY or GROUP BY must contains only columns from the first table in the join queue, so that's why the use of the STRAIGHT_JOIN clause and the two slightly different queries.

To avoid confusion, I'm going to assign a number to various query configuration:

1. order by date with STRAIGHT_JOIN clause
2. order by score with STRAIGHT_JOIN clause
3. order by date without STRAIGHT_JOIN clause
4. order by score without STRAIGHT_JOIN clause

Following is query 1, takes about 2.5 seconds to complete:

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN item.id AS id
FROM item 
INNER JOIN score ON item.id = score.item_id 
LEFT JOIN url ON item.url_id = url.id 
LEFT JOIN doc ON url.doc_id = doc.id 
INNER JOIN feed ON feed.id = item.feed_id 
INNER JOIN user_feed ON feed.id = user_feed.feed_id AND score.user_id = user_feed.user_id 
LEFT JOIN star ON item.id = star.item_id AND score.user_id = star.user_id 
JOIN unseen ON item.id = unseen.item_id AND score.user_id = unseen.user_id 
WHERE score.user_id = 1 AND user_feed.id = 7 
ORDER BY zen_time DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Following is query 2 (first join tables are inverted and the ordering column is different), takes only about 0.01 seconds to complete:

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN item.id AS id
FROM score
INNER JOIN item ON item.id = score.item_id 
LEFT JOIN url ON item.url_id = url.id 
LEFT JOIN doc ON url.doc_id = doc.id 
INNER JOIN feed ON feed.id = item.feed_id 
INNER JOIN user_feed ON feed.id = user_feed.feed_id AND score.user_id = user_feed.user_id 
LEFT JOIN star ON item.id = star.item_id AND score.user_id = star.user_id 
JOIN unseen ON item.id = unseen.item_id AND score.user_id = unseen.user_id 
WHERE score.user_id = 1 AND user_feed.id = 7 
ORDER BY score DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Following are the EXPLAIN results for the queries.

Explain for query 1:
[image]

Explain for query 2:
[image]

Explain for query 3:
[image]

Explain for query 4:
[image]

Profiler result for query 1:
[image]

Profiler result for query 2:
[image]

Profiler result for query 3:
[image]

Profiler result for query 4:
[image]

Following are tables definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE `doc` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`md5` char(32) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `Md5_index` (`md5`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `feed` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`url` text NOT NULL,
`title` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
FULLTEXT KEY `Title_url_index` (`title`,`url`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `item` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`feed_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`url_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`md5` char(32) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `Md5_index` (`md5`),
KEY `Zen_time_index` (`zen_time`),
KEY `Feed_index` (`feed_id`),
KEY `Url_index` (`url_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `score` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`item_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`score` float DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `User_item_index` (`user_id`,`item_id`),
KEY Score_index (`score`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `star` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`item_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `User_item_index` (`user_id`,`item_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `unseen` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`item_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `User_item_index` (`user_id`,`item_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `url` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`doc_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY Doc_index (`doc_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `user` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `IDX_Email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `user_feed` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`feed_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `User_feed_index` (`user_id`,`feed_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here are the row counts for the tables involved in the query:

```
Score: 68657
Item: 197602
Url: 198354
Doc: 186113
Feed: 754
User_feed: 721
Star: 0
Unseen: 150762
```

---

**Which approach should I take since my program needs to be able to order results both by zen_time and score in the fastest way possible?**

Comment: How long do query 3 and query 4 take to execute? You have only said about queries 1 and 2.

Comment: Why does query 2 have the join tables inverted? Query 2 is much faster because the first thing it does is uses your where clause to filter on score BEFORE doing any joins, while Query 1 has to try to join all (unfiltered) items..

Comment: @GarethD Sorry, forgot to add them. They are as fast as query 2

Comment: @StevieG According to MySQL doc pointed out in the Stack Overflow question I linked, the ORDER BY column must be one of the first table in the join, so when I order by score.score I put score table as the first one in the join, when I order by item.zen_time I put item as the first one in the join.

Comment: So if you run query 2 with the order by changed to `ORDER BY zen_time DESC`, your performance is worse?

Comment: The answer is don't use `STRAIGHT_JOIN`, it is essentially you saying that you know better than the query optimiser, and in the case of the first query you don't if it takes 2.5 seconds to run with `STRAIGHT_JOIN` AND 0.1 seconds to run without. Without it MySQL is free to determine which it deems would be the most efficient table to be the *1st table* with it is obliged to use what you define as the first table and maintain the join order.

Comment: @StevieG Query 2 ordered by score 0.2 seconds, query 2 ordered by zen_time 1.44 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the different query speeds I decided to make an even more accurate analysis based on the various results I want to achieve.

The result sets I need are four:

1. Select all the items from a specific feed, order them by SCORE.score (intelligent order)
2. Select all the items from a specific feed, order them by ITEM.zen_time (time order)
3. Select all the items, order them by SCORE.score (intelligent order)
4. Select all the items, order them by ITEM.zen_time (time order)

The query so has to be adapted to those conditions, and its variable parts are:

- STRAIGHT_JOIN yes/no
- First JOIN table score/item
- WHERE condition on specific feed yes/no
- ORDER BY score/zen_time

All of the tests have been executed with the SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE instruction.

Following are the results:
[image]

Now it's clear what I have to do:

1. No STRAIGHT_JOIN, first JOIN table SCORE
2. No STRAIGHT_JOIN, first JOIN table SCORE
3. STRAIGHT_JOIN (I did beat MySQL engine here :D ), first JOIN table SCORE
4. STRAIGHT_JOIN (I did beat MySQL engine here :D ), first JOIN table ITEM