# mysql - slow query due to high index cardinality

Tags: mysql

I've got the following mysql query taking approx 55 seconds to complete

```
SELECT this_.id AS y0_ FROM event this_ 
  INNER JOIN member m1_ ON this_.member_id=m1_.id 
  INNER JOIN event_type et2_ ON this_.type_id=et2_.id 
WHERE m1_.submission_id=40646 AND et2_.name IN ('Salary') 
ORDER BY m1_.ni_number ASC, m1_.ident1 ASC, m1_.ident2 ASC, m1_.ident3 ASC, m1_.id ASC, et2_.name ASC LIMIT 15;
```

If I remove the join/where/order to the 'event_type' table, then the query runs in under 1 second.

So something clearly up with my join to the 'event_type' table, but a similar query in another database with similar database volumes runs absolutely fine. So my suspicion is something wrong with this 1 database.

The 'show create table' of the 'event' table is:

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `data_size` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `encoded_data` mediumblob,
  `last_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `member_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `parent_event_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `updated_by` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `failed_workflow_case` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `failed_workflow_task` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK5C6729A2434DA80` (`member_id`),
  KEY `FK5C6729AE4E22C6E` (`type_id`),
  KEY `IND_parent_event_id` (`parent_event_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK5C6729A2434DA80` FOREIGN KEY (`member_id`) REFERENCES `member` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK5C6729AE4E22C6E` FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `event_type` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=46241198 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The EXPLAIN of the query is:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys                       | key               | key_len | ref                      | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | et2_  | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,IND_name                    | IND_name          | 257     | const                    |    1 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | this_ | NULL       | ref    | FK5C6729A2434DA80,FK5C6729AE4E22C6E | FK5C6729AE4E22C6E | 8       | iconnect.et2_.id         | 3303 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | m1_   | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,IND_submission_id           | PRIMARY           | 8       | iconnect.this_.member_id |    1 |     5.00 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

The indexes from the 'event' table are:

```
+-------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name            | Seq_in_index | Column_name     | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| event |          0 | PRIMARY             |            1 | id              | A         |    14307622 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| event |          1 | FK5C6729A2434DA80   |            1 | member_id       | A         |     4680601 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| event |          1 | FK5C6729AE4E22C6E   |            1 | type_id         | A         |        4360 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| event |          1 | IND_parent_event_id |            1 | parent_event_id | A         |      114404 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

What jumps out at me from this is:
1. why is the EXPLAIN going through 3303 rows and the FK5C6729AE4E22C6E index?
2. why does the FK5C6729AE4E22C6E index have a cardinality of 4360 when there are only 17 rows in the 'event_type' table? could this incorrect cardinality be affecting the query optimizer?

I've done an ANALYZE TABLE on both 'event' and 'event_type' and this has made no difference.

Any suggestions?

---

execute plan from other server with the same data (loaded from a dump file):

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+-------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+-----------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys                       | key               | key_len | ref             | rows  | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+-------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+-----------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | et2_  | NULL       | ALL  | PRIMARY                             | NULL              | NULL    | NULL            |    17 |    10.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | m1_   | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,IND_submission_id           | IND_submission_id | 8       | const           | 27992 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | this_ | NULL       | ref  | FK5C6729A2434DA80,FK5C6729AE4E22C6E | FK5C6729A2434DA80 | 8       | iconnect.m1_.id |     3 |    11.11 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+-------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+-----------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633406/using-index-using-temporary-using-filesort-how-to-fix-this

Comment: a) The statistic is an estimate. MySQL samples random parts, (depending by your configuration), and extrapolates; a factor 200 can indeed have an impact on index choice though b) the most relevant table seems to be `member` (and specifically indexes on `submission_id` or `ni_number`), not `event`. Please add that table, and make sure they are identical on both servers c) since you already seem to have the correct execution plan on your other server: please add it. Then try it (by e.g. forcing the indexes). Figuring out why MySQL doesn't find that plan on its own would be the 2nd step.

Comment: Thanks for the update; that execution plan is about what I expected; is the number of rows per submission id correct? In that case, the incorrect statistics seem to be the problem (3k < 27k, while it actually should be (700k > 27k), and I assume they are (more) correct on the other server. Check `innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages` (assuming `innodb_stats_persistent` is enabled); I'd assume the default (20) should be fine, but make sure noone lowered or disabled it. In any case, the current value seems to be too low, so increase it and try `analyze` again.

Comment: There are 43k event records for 14k members with the submission_id specified, 14k of those event records are for the event_type record specified by the name arg. So my query should be finding 14k results but returning only the first 15. I'm failing to grasp how that is relating to the rows returns in either of the execution plans.

Comment: The innodb stats are persisted and the sample_pages is 20 on both servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increasing innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages from 20 to 100, then running ANALYZE TABLE on event/member tables changed the cardinality of the indexes and the execution plan, then the query ran in under 1 second. Thanks to Solarflare for the suggestion.