# Many to Many Join on Current Owned Rows

Tags: mysql

Essentially trying to write a MySQL query (can be any version) for a locations index view that shows all the items that have current associations with the locations. The item_location tables is representative of where and when the items have moved.

```
items
______________
| id | name  |
--------------
| 1  | item1 |
| 2  | item2 |
| 3  | item3 |
| 4  | item4 |
--------------

locations
______________
| id | city  |
--------------
| 1  | city1 |
| 2  | city2 |
| 3  | city3 |
| 4  | city4 |
--------------

item_location
_______________________________________________________
| id | item_id | location_id | date                   |
------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | 1       | 1           | 1998-01-01 04:00:00    |
| 2  | 1       | 2           | 1998-01-02 04:00:00    |
| 3  | 2       | 1           | 1998-01-03 04:00:00    |
| 4  | 3       | 1           | 1998-01-04 04:00:00    |
| 4  | 4       | 3           | 1999-01-04 04:00:00    |
| 4  | 4       | 4           | 1999-02-04 04:00:00    |
-------------------------------------------------------

expected output (with limit 3):
____________________________________________________________________________________________
| location.id | location.city | items                                                      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1           | city1         | [{"id":"2", "name": "item2"}, {"id":"3", "name": "item3"}] |
| 2           | city2         | [{"id":"1", "name": "item1"}]                              |
| 3           | city3         | [], '', or null because city4 has latest date.             |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am open to restructuring my database if there is a more common or efficient practice for such a situation.

I have been using JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT("id", item.id, "name", item.name)) to build the arrays of json objects. I am open if there is a better/common/performant alternative for that as well.

---

I have created a reproducible example of my situation that is runnable.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE `item_location` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `location_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `location_id` (`location_id`),
  KEY `machine_id` (`item_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `locations` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `items` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, '1405'), (2, '1447'), (3, '1641');

INSERT INTO `locations` (`id`, `city`) VALUES
(1, 'Kingsville'), (2, '
Wright City'), (3, 'Racine');

INSERT INTO `item_location` (`id`, `location_id`, `item_id`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 3, 1, '1992-01-14 05:00:00'),
(2, 3, 2, '1993-02-05 05:00:00'),
(3, 3, 3, '1997-05-13 04:00:00'),
(4, 1, 3, '2018-01-15 05:00:00'),
(5, 2, 3, '2006-07-01 04:00:00')
```

---

**Attempted Query #1**

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_location.location_id, locations.city, date, JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT("id", items.id, "name", items.name)) AS items
FROM item_location 
INNER JOIN items ON item_location.item_id = items.id
INNER JOIN locations ON item_location.location_id = locations.id
GROUP BY items.name, item_location.location_id, date;
```

```
| location_id | date                | city         | items                       |
| ----------- | ------------------- | ------------ | --------------------------- |
| 3           | 1992-01-14 05:00:00 | Racine       | [{"id": 1, "name": "1405"}] |
| 3           | 1993-02-05 05:00:00 | Racine       | [{"id": 2, "name": "1447"}] |
| 1           | 2018-01-15 05:00:00 | Kingsville   | [{"id": 3, "name": "1641"}] |
| 2           | 2006-07-01 04:00:00 | Wright City  | [{"id": 3, "name": "1641"}] |
| 3           | 1997-05-13 04:00:00 | Racine       | [{"id": 3, "name": "1641"}] |

---
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

expected outcome:

```
| location_id | city         | items                                                    |
| ----------- | ------------ | ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————— |
| 3           | Racine       | [{"id": "1", "name": "1405"}, {"id": "2", "name": "1447"}]  |
| 1           | Kingsville   | [{"id": "3", "name": "1641"}]                              |
| 2           | Wright City  | []                                                       |
```

### Here is my closest query except I'm not sure if there is a way for MySQL to be able to be able to know which item is the most current owner of the location:

**Query #1**

```
select `locations`.`id`, `locations`.`city` as `city`, `itms`.`items` from locations
left join (
SELECT il.location_id AS id, JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT("name", i.name)) AS items
FROM   item_location il
JOIN   items i ON i.id = il.item_id
GROUP  BY il.location_id
) itms USING (id)  
order by `city`;
```

```
| id  | city         | items                                                  |
| --- | ------------ | ------------------------------------------------------ |
| 2   | Wright City | [{"name": "1641"}]                                 |
| 1   | Kingsville   | [{"name": "1641"}]                                     |
| 3   | Racine       | [{"name": "1405"}, {"name": "1447"}, {"name": "1641"}] |
```

---

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Strawberry That may be my last resort. I could grab a handful of locations and either use multiple queries and sort through the full list of item_locations or json parse the array results and just figure out which items should go where. I'd like to leverage multiple options incase of performance issues handling the data restructure in the business logic or on the client side.

Comment: And please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_location.location_id, locations.city, JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT("id", items.id, "name", items.name)) AS items
FROM item_location 
INNER JOIN items ON item_location.item_id = items.id
INNER JOIN locations ON item_location.location_id = locations.id
GROUP BY items.name
```

You can add the date as required to the above query.

The answer to your question would be the following are the areas for improvement. Learn about the MySQL `EXPLAIN`. [Read more](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html).

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT item_location.location_id, locations.city, JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT("id", items.id, "name", items.name)) AS items FROM item_location INNER JOIN items ON item_location.item_id = items.id INNER JOIN locations ON item_location.location_id = locations.id GROUP BY items.name
```

[image]

You need to learn how to remove Using temporary; Using filesort etc. There are ample of tutorials on the internet to learn.

[Using index, using temporary, using filesort - how to fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633406/using-index-using-temporary-using-filesort-how-to-fix-this)

Let me know if you need further help on this.

Answer (score 0):

The only answer I've found is that the use of JSON_ARRAYAGG (or JSON_OBJECTAGG) necessitates the use of filesort by the query planner. I'm looking for a solution to this as well, but it may be impossible to avoid.
https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=7987

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).