mysql groupby+orderby query is too slow
I am currently preparing to write a query related to statistics value.
Currently, there are two indexes in the DB's vehicle_trip_statistics_history table.
The vehicle_trip_statistics_history table contains information fields related to daily driving distance (trip_distance column) with device_id and base_date column.
The index of this table consists of idx_vehicle_trip_statistics_history_01 (device_id, base_date), idx_vehicle_trip_statistics_history_02 (base_date, device_id).
Currently, there are about 2500 device_ids, and base_date is accumulated from 20231101 (YYYYMMDD).
Accordingly, I want to find the summation of the driving distance for each_id for dates in a specific range.
select device_id, sum(trip_distance) as tp
from vehicle_trip_statistics_history
where base_date >= '20240101' and base_date <= '20240613'
group by device_id
limit 10;

The above query takes about 130 ms and the result of EXPLAIN query is as follows



id
select_type
table
partitions
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
filtered
Extra




1
SIMPLE
vehicle_trip_statistics_history

index
idx_vehicle_trip_statistics_history_01,idx_vehicle_trip_statistics_history_02
idx_vehicle_trip_statistics_history_01
36

2826
50.0
Using where



However, the problem is that setting limits based on order by is time consuming.
select device_id, sum(trip_distance) as tp
from vehicle_trip_statistics_history
where base_date >= '20240101' and base_date <= '20240613'
group by device_id
order by tp desc
limit 10;

This query takes about 2073 ms and the result of EXPLAIN query is as follows.



id
select_type
table
partitions
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
filtered
Extra




1
SIMPLE
vehicle_trip_statistics_history

index
idx_vehicle_trip_statistics_history_01,idx_vehicle_trip_statistics_history_02
idx_vehicle_trip_statistics_history_01
36

340,778
50.0
Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort



What steps should be taken to solve this extremely time-consuming problem? In general, in these cases, is it processed order by and limit step at application level rather than the query?

Put the quick bit ie the select - group by in a cte (or sub query) then order and limit in the main query.

You can't avoid sorting by sum(trip_distance) as tp. This causes Using temporary; Using filesort - expensive part of query. See this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633406/using-index-using-temporary-using-filesort-how-to-fix-this)

Optimized query using a subquery:
SELECT device_id, SUM(trip_distance) AS tp
FROM (
    SELECT device_id, trip_distance
    FROM vehicle_trip_statistics_history
    WHERE base_date >= '20240101' AND base_date <= '20240613'
) AS subquery
GROUP BY device_id
ORDER BY tp DESC
LIMIT 10;


The time consumption of the modified query and the previous one is almost similar.. Even if I query with EXPLAIN, there is no change in the execution plan.
