# Does MySQL allow using syntax with straight join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, rdbms

I'm trying to convert my query from inner join to straight join. My original query was:
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM x AS t1 INNER JOIN x AS t2 USING (id);` And I'd like to simply replace inner join to straight join: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM x AS t1 STRAIGHT_JOIN x AS t2 USING (id);`

The first query executes as expected but the second query throws syntax error. If I change the query to simply `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM x AS t1 STRAIGHT_JOIN x AS t2 ON t1.id=t2.id`

Does MySQL disallow straight join with using? I didn't see that in the docs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/516720/1190388

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, MySQL disallows straight join with USING. The syntax rules in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html show this:

```
join_table:
    table_reference [INNER | CROSS] JOIN table_factor [join_condition]
  | table_reference STRAIGHT_JOIN table_factor
  | table_reference STRAIGHT_JOIN table_factor ON conditional_expr
  | table_reference {LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER] JOIN table_reference join_condition
  | table_reference NATURAL [{LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER]] JOIN table_factor

join_condition:
    ON conditional_expr
  | USING (column_list)
```

You can see that the syntax with `STRAIGHT_JOIN` allows only no condition, or an `ON` clause. Other joins types allow `[join_condition]` which is another syntax rule that expands to either `ON` clause or a`USING` expression.

I don't know if there's a good reason for this different treatment of `STRAIGHT_JOIN`. Perhaps it was simply an oversight. For what it's worth, this was reported as a bug back in 2008: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=35268
But there's no explanation for the difference, and no sign that it has any priority to get fixed.

As a workaround, you could apply the STRAIGHT_JOIN query modifier to the whole query, and then use standard JOIN operators:

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN COUNT(*) FROM x AS t1 INNER JOIN x AS t2 USING (id)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can go for `NATURAL JOIN` in MySQL like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM x AS t1 NATURAL JOIN x AS t2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [reference manual for `JOIN` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html):

> `STRAIGHT_JOIN` is similar to `JOIN`, except that the left table is always read before the right table. This can be used for those (few) cases for which the join optimizer puts the tables in the wrong order.